# CakePHP and User login function

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

Here is a simple CakePHP login function (example taken from the CakePHP cookbook):

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $message = 'Username or password is incorrect';
            $this->Session->setFlash(__($message), 'default', array(), 'auth');
        }
    }
}
```

During testing of this login function I found out that:

```
if ($this->Auth->login()) {
    // ...
}
```

It lets a user to login even if authorization was done earlier. For example, if I logged in as *User1* and without a call to logout function I'm trying to log in as *User2* - I will get the next **error:**

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: User [APP/Controller/UsersController.php, line 83]
```

In this case I can hide a login form from the user. Is it a correct way?

**Update**: what can you say about the next code snippet:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
            $this->Auth->logout();
        }
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $message = 'Invalid login or password';
            $this->Session->setFlash(__($message), 'default', array(), 'auth');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tutorial [Simple Acl controlled Application - part 2](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/part-two.html#logging-in) in the cookbook suggests that you read out the data with `SessionComponent`.

You can also use the [`AuthComponent`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#AuthComponent::user) to check whether a user is already logged in or not. Use `$this->Auth->user()` in your controller. You can also pass a key to the first parameter to get a specific column of your `users` table or skip it to get all of the user's information. It returns `Null` if the user is not logged in or the key does not exist.

Your login method could look like the following one (additions marked with a plus `+` and `SessionComponent` is used):

```
public function login() {
+   if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
+       $this->Session->setFlash('You are logged in!');
+       return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
+   }
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $message = 'Username or password is incorrect';
            $this->Session->setFlash(__($message), 'default', array(), 'auth');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this might be a simple fix- in your login controller function you can check to see if a session variable IsUserLoggedIn is set. Set it if it's not then continue the authentication process, else, redirect to some message page.

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        //check to see if user is logged in.
        if(isset($this->Session->read('IsUserLoggedIn'))) {
        ##perform redirection to "Already Logged In" message
        }

        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            //write the IsLoggedIn variable to the session.
            $this->Session->write('IsUserLoggedIn', true);

            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default',  array(), 'auth');
        }
    }
}
```

And on logout, delete this session variable:

```
  $this->Session->delete('IsUserLoggedIn');
```

EDIT: Moved the session write to inside the auth block.

Comment: Shouldn't the  $this->Session->write('IsUserLoggedIn', true); be inside the ($this->Auth->login()) condition block ? I will assume you want to set the IsUserLoggedIn to true only if your are able to authenticate the first time around.